# inkscape stroke inaccurate

Tags: graphics, inkscape, vector-graphics

I am trying to add a stroke to a rectangle object, but if I add a 1px stroke, it places it 0.5px outside the edge of the rectangle and 0.5px inside the rectangle.  I find this to be annoying when I want an object to be exactly 5px by 5px and it ends up becoming 6px by 6px.

Is there a setting anywhere which places the stroke within the rectangle edge so a 5px by 5px square remains a 5px by 5px square.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding another object just for the stroke. You may also want to modify how the intersection of the objects (Add, Subtract, Multiply) for different effects.

You can then group them to treat them as one object so you can resize them together.

Comment: Seems very difficult to do if I am trying to add a stroke to a box with round edges.

Comment: I see I can use ctrl-d to clone an object, then ctrl+( or ctrl+) to change the size.  Is it possible to change the size by exactly 1px all over?